# AWS iot rule trigger for lambda action issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am creating AWS IOT rule using sdk from my code with lambda function as action.
Rule is getting created successfully, but its not getting triggered. It will start getting triggered only after I go the the UI page select the action and click on update button on the right hand side.

Any help to resolve the issue will be helpfull.

Comment: Enable IoT service logs, do something that would trigger the function, then check the log to see if there is an issue reported.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem today, this is my solution.

You need to add permission to your target lambda,
you can create a lambda, then run this code.
You need change the functionName first.
Then go your target Lambda function and click the permission, 
you will see the permission in your left side.

```
response = client.add_permission(
 FunctionName='Lambda_Name',
 StatementId='FunctionPermission',
 Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
 Principal="iot.amazonaws.com",
 SourceAccount = "yourAccount")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer by @saint, when an IoT rule is created by SDK/CloudFormation, **the rule does not automatically add an invoke permission on the target lambda**.
So we need to manually perform an additional step of adding the missing permission to the target lambda.

Here is the full code sample (JavaScript)

```
import {AddPermissionCommand, Lambda} from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda";

const lambdaClient = new Lambda({region: process.env.AWS_REGION});
async function addInvokePermissionToIoTRule() {
  const input = {
    FunctionName: <Name of your function>, // required
    StatementId: <Name of your Iot Rule>, // required
    Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction", // required
    Principal: "iot.amazonaws.com", // required
    SourceArn: <ARN of your Iot Rule>
  };
  const command = new AddPermissionCommand(input);
  const response = await lambdaClient.send(command);
  return response;
}
```